# inter property reference with in an object using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using Mongoose and my model is like-

```
{
first_name:{
 type:String
},
lastName:{
 type:String
}
name:{
 type:String
}
}
```

I want whenever i create object with firstName and lastName , name field should be set automatically to firstName+" "+ lastName.

can i use something like we do in Java as-

```
name = this.firstName+this.lastName
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try it with `pre.('save'....`

Comment: it seems virtual is a memory friendly option http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

Answer (score 1):

Try it with [`pre`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre) method

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.name = this.lastName + this.firstName;
    next();
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', schema);

function saveData() {
    var p = new Person({
        lastName: 'DD',
        firstName: 'ss'
    });

    p.save(function(err, obj) {
      console.log(obj);
    }); 
}
```

And result

```
{ __v: 0,
  name: 'DDss',
  lastName: 'DD',
  firstName: 'ss',
  _id: 56af4489b81a1f2903a13608 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer using a virtual for fullname.

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        first: String
      , last: String
    }
});
PersonSchema
.virtual('name.full')
.get(function () {
    return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
});
```